# Pure transport delay? (Nyquist plot)

Tags: control, control-system, control-theory, nyquist-plot

How does pure transport delay affect the Nyquist plot, and how is it possible to find the maximum value of the delay, such that the system stays stable even after delay is introduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It rotates the locus of points on the plot.  Maximum delay before the system becomes unstable the phase margin divided by the crossover freq.